# Animated series with three girls who find magical rings

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

My daughter is trying to find a series she watched on Netflix in 2017 or 2018. We are in the USA.

There are 6 main characters, three heroes and three villains, all girls. They are normal girls until they find magical rings and get special powers. She doesn't remember what the powers are, or if their clothes transform, but they stay human.

The characters are teenagers, and at least one of the heroes has relatively long, purple hair.

The villains are always trying to steal the rings from the heroes.

The setting is contemporary as far as she remembers. The villains and heroes at least know of each other, but she's not sure if any of it takes place at school.

She says the animation style is similar to anime, though it may be western animation.

I know this isn't a lot to go on, but she's really upset she can't find it.

Comment: What do they transform into?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm editing to add more info as she remembers. I guess they don't actually transform, unless it's just their clothes

Comment: Are the heroes and villains peers, or just random people who get powers?  Is the setting contemporary (if so:  city, suburb, town or rural?) or something else (if so:  science-type future, apocalyptic-type future, mediaeval-type fantasy, diesel-punk victorian, usw.?)

Comment: @DavidW I added as much more details as she could give me

Comment: Do the villains also use rings to transform, or is it just the heroes?

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern She doesn't think so, but that they could presumably use the rings if they ever stole them from the heroes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this quite matches but could this be [*Mysticons*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7252220/?ref_=adv_li_tt)? A series that ran from 2017 to 2018? It appears to be about 4 female lead characters [The Mysticons](https://mysticons.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mysticons) fighting the evil of 4 female antagonists [The Vexicons](https://mysticons.fandom.com/wiki/The_Vexicons). There's quite [a detailed synopsis on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysticons):

> The series is set in the mystical world of Gemina and in its capitol called Drake City, following the adventures of four teenage girls who are chosen by the all-powerful Dragon Disk to become legendary heroes known as the Mysticons. Arkayna, Emerald, Zarya and Piper undertake an arduous quest to find four spellbooks and animal-themed bracers of mystical power to form the Codex. This will grant them their full strength and abilities necessary to save their world from Dreadbane, who seeks to release Necrafa, the leader of the Spectral Hand and Queen of the Undead. When Necrafa is freed she betrays Headbanger and throws him into where she was banished by Imani Firewing, the original Mysticon Dragon Mage, a millennium ago.

One of the main protagonists does have purple hair. It doesn't look like they gain their powers from rings, rather spellbooks and bracers, however, at some point magical rings do come into play.

You can see the trailer here:

---

I actually found this by searching through [this IMDb search for "Animation, female-protagonist (Sorted by Release Date Descending)"](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=animation&keywords=female-protagonist&sort=release_date,desc&start=101&ref_=adv_nxt) and checking the relevant results.

Comment: What is a bracer?

Comment: @M.A.Golding - An arm gauntlet thing

Comment: @M.A.Golding It's armor that you wear on your lower arm/wrist, mainly archers wear them to protect their arm from the bowstring.

Comment: Unfortunately, she says no, it's not. For some reason I can't seem to figure out how to do that sort of search on the site.

Comment: Not to be mistaken for a vambrace, which is always a complete cylinder to form armor for the forearms.

Comment: @methuseus It's not easy to find but click the All dropdown next to search then Advanced search and then advanced title search and it takes you to [this page](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/).

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Flowering Heart](https://flowering-heart.fandom.com/wiki/Flowering_Heart_(series)) and it was taken off of Netflix and season 3 was canceled.

> With the world of magic being slowly corrupted by Hopeless Energy, Prince Chess flees to the Human World to prevent the withering of the Heart Flower. Three fifth-graders of the Problem Solving Club, Ari, Suha, and Min, finds him as a strange-looking hamster form. They later team up to collect Hopeful Energy to save Flowering Kingdom. Unbeknownst to them, Prince Trump and Shuel, their enemies, are seeking Hopeless Energy.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you [edit your answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/260814/edit) to explain how this matches the description provided in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is loli rock, I know this is a late response and you may have already found it but I just wanted to say this. I was looking for this show and I just found it

Comment: Please add some information to explain why this matches (eg quotes, images).